# Getting local Printer Names in c# web application

Tags: .net, crystal-reports

I created one simple crystal report as a web application using c# codes.When i print using Printtoprinter method it prints with the default printer.I want to list all the printer in the client side from that list i want to choose one printer to Print..Can any one one help me the code in c#? or give any idea about this ?

Comment: Your app is executing on the server, not the client. It can't access the client's printers.

Comment: Ok..any javascript call will work for this?

Comment: I might be asking silly questions but i want the report to printed using the LAN printers...Means printer installed in Network using that i want to print..can any one help in this..

Answer (score 0):

As you want is not possible from crystal report or c# side.

"Printtoprinter"  is used to print directly without prompting on default printer of server where your application host/deploy.

As you need, that you achieve by HTML - javascript function (onload or .ready function).

For this you have to generate a HTML from your c# code and open in another page with jquery - .ready function called which get the list of printer

To get the printer list. use javascript funciton

window.print();

Check the links with example.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_print.asp

http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/351577/How-to-print-in-asp-net

http://forums.asp.net/t/1561011.aspx?How+to+print+a+web+form+using+asp+net+with+c+

Comment: I might be asking silly questions but i want the report to printed using the LAN printers...Means printer installed in Network using that i want to print..can any one help in this..

Comment: Hi Dear,   For the same reason or question, I give the above answer. I know your logic, but in web, we don't know at which and how much printer are installed at client machine. For this we just create a html and run window.print command , which search and popup the installed printer. Now client decision comes to where he/she print. It is not handled by us.      In crystal report - "Printtoprinter" always print on default printer of server as our application is host on server , that why.